# jq error while parsing json file inside jenkins Shell

Tags: json, error-handling, compilation, runtime-error, jq

I want to parse the value of the filepath from the json. while parsing it via jq and seeing issue with respect to  not defined at top level. Please find the json details and the error below:

```
"environment":{
             "stage":{
                       "testing":[
{
 "tag":"1.0"
  "filepath":"C:/test/conf"
   "hostname":"test"
}]}}

**command Used in Execute shell:**
 jq -r ".'environment.stage.testing[].filePath' env.json

**Error Faced**:
jq: error: environments/0 is not defined at <top-level>, line 1:
environment.stage.testing[].filePath
jq: 1 compile error

TIA
```

Answer (score 2):

1. The posted data conforms with the requirements of [HJSON](http://hjson.org/), and can be converted to JSON by:

   hjson -j
2. The jq filter includes `.filePath` whereas the HJSON only includes a key named "filepath".
3. The filter that corresponds with the posted data is:

   .environment.stage.testing[].filepath

Putting the above together:

```
$ hjson -j < so-jenkins-shell.hjson |
  jq -r '.environment.stage.testing[].filepath'
C:/test/conf
```

Answer (score 0):

Provided you fixed your JSON file by adding comma to separate the elements `tag`, `filepath` and `hostname`:

```
{
  "environment": {
    "stage": {
      "testing": [
        {
          "tag": "1.0",
          "filepath": "C:/test/conf",
          "hostname": "test"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

You can use this `jq` command:

```
jq -r '.environment.stage.testing[].filepath' env.json
```

Notice the keyword `filepath` instead of `filePath` in your command.

Comment: Already the elements are seperated by comma only. Also that filepath value is corrected , still experiencing the same error

Comment: Put a `{` before `"environment"` and a `}` at the end of the file. The command will work then.

Comment: Yeah added the {} before and after environment, that is also not giving success.

Comment: Difficult to see what you changed in your input file. But for sure, if you take the JSON data from this post, the command will work. It is likely a typo in your input data.